# Taking Optional Arguments in C

Tags: c, command-line, command-line-arguments

so I'm a bit stuck on how I am to consider optional command-line arguments for my C program. My program is to take in several different inputs and then based on those inputs it has to do something. For example, my compiled program could take the following arguments

```
./program [-optional1, -optional2] compulsoryInput [-optionalFile]
```

How would I keep track of what has been taken as command line input? would I just need to do a bunch of if statements in my main function like

> if (argc == 1) {
> } else if (argc == 2) {
> }

And so on?? How am I to consider every possible combination of input that could be put in. Thank you, sorry if the question is a bit confusing or vague.

Comment: `argc` would not be the thing to check for in terms of determining combinations. Instead have variables with default/null values that represent each arg value. Then parse each arg and set the relevant variable. After all args have been parsed then check the variables for any mandatory values that have not been set and use any optional variables that have. Or just use an existing lib function such as [getopt](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) if that is available on your platform.

Comment: Unless you are setting out to write your own command-line parser, use an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

> would I just need to do a bunch of if statements in my main function

Well... not necessarily `if` statements.. not necessarily in `main` but...

Standard C has no functions/framework to "automatically" parse the the command line arguments. You have to write code for it. That code can be written in many ways. For instance you can use a `for` loop like:

```
for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
{
    // Parse the string argv[i]

    // For this you can use whatever statements that
    // make sense for your type of arguments.
    // if-statements, switch-statements, strcmp, character ==
    // and so on
}
```

or

```
for (int i = 1; argv[i]; ++i)
{
    // Parse the string argv[i]
}
```

or some other way.

You can pass the arguments that `main` received to another function so that you don't have to "polute" `main` with that code.

There are so many ways to write such code.

There are also a number of free libs doing such stuff - just search the net.

**very simple example**

Say you want

```
./program [-a] [-b] someTextString
          ^^^^^^^^^
          optional
```

You could do:

```
int option_a_present = 0;
int option_b_present = 0;
char* input_text = NULL;
for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
{
    if (argv[i][0] == '-' && argv[i][1] == 'a')
    {
        option_a_present = 1;
    }
    else if (argv[i][0] == '-' && argv[i][1] == 'b')
    {
        option_b_present = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        input_text = argv[i];
    }
}
if (input_text == NULL)
{
     // Error - missing mandatory argument
     exit(1);
}

....
```

Note: The parsing in this example is very simple and allows/accepts stuff like, e.g. **./program -aa -b Hello Hallo ---k**. A better implementation would do more syntax checks than the example code.

And remember: It's your program so you decide the rules for calling the program.

```
./program [-a] [-b] someTextString
          ^^^^^^^^^
          optional

What is legal?

./program Hello           // Legal
./program -a Hello        // Legal
./program -b Hello        // Legal
./program -a -b Hello     // Legal
./program -a -a Hello     // Legal ??
./program -b -a Hello     // Legal ??
./program Hello -b -a     // Legal ??
./program -aa Hello       // Legal ??
./program Hello World     // Legal ??
./program Hello -c        // Legal ??
./program -a -b Hello -c  // Legal ??
....
```

You decide the rules... The rules you select are those that your parser needs to check.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but how will I know the position of each variable then because the program could take say ' ./program -optional1 compulsoryInput optionalFile ' which would mean the position of compulsoryInput is argv[2]. It could also take               
' ./program -optional1 -optional 2 compulsoryInput ' which would mean it's position would be argv[3]. How do I keep track of each location??

Comment: @Mully5474 It's your program so **you** define the rules, i.e. how the arguments can be provided. Your C code then parse the arguments following those rules. There are no standard for that... you decide.

Comment: @Mully5474 Added a simple example

Comment: Thanks so much that really helps! I'll give it a go I think I understand what you mean now